# How to keep code behind UI organized?

Tags: user-interface, language-agnostic

In my experience code behind UI can easily get ugly, and inorganized, e.g. long functions, lots of variables etc. 
How do you manage the code behind UI?

Answer (score 2):

The [MVC pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller) is often used to impose some structure and organisation.

Following the principles of [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_(object-oriented_design)) OO design and similar ideas helps.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your programming-language.

Threre are a lot of QA-Tools for different languages. Have a look at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_quality)

Which languages and techniques do you use?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use 'immediate mode' UIs. It basically boils down to only caring about the UI element you're currently focussed on and binding the variables with data-side app variables. This is the opposite of retention mode UIs

[Great video here.](http://mollyrocket.com/861)